# Calculating kwh required to get an aircraft to 1000' based on climb rate

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, estimation, aircraft

I'll start with the question and then provide context: to get an aircraft to 1000', does a steeper climb angle consume more energy? Assume the flying speed and angle of attack stay constant. This means the coefficients of lift and drag stay constant.

Context:

I'm trying to build a basic calculator that outputs the kwh required to get an electric powered hang glider to 1000'. My first attempt is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOWFBWTjYjzgTAwhfQpxgTqjzGBhD4zJOt-nyNrNo94/edit#gid=0

It uses a method I found in this forum: https://endless-sphere.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=110570#p1626972

The output numbers are actually quite accurate for a 5 minute (200fpm) climb to 1000'. We know from pilots that the kwh used matches up with the calculator.

However, something seems off to me when I increase the flight time (climb more slowly), the energy requirement drops. Doesn't seem right. So assuming my best L/D (best lift coeff) is 12 (same as glide ratio), and my best speed to fly is 25mph, how would changing the climb time change the energy usage? I'm climbing at a steeper or shallower angle, but is the angle of attack changing if my airspeed is not? I doubt my batteries would last forever if I took forever to get to 1000'.

This question seems related to a number of youtube videos I've watched and posts here like this: [Is it more efficient to drive fast uphill?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409389/is-it-more-efficient-to-drive-fast-uphill?newreg=76a7c7aea296418399be018b0611c097)

Comment: The drag probably does not stay the same for different air speeds. After all, you are pushing the air out of the way at different speeds so you would expect going faster will use more energy per unit distance.

Comment: No. The airspeed stays the same at 25mph. The angle is steeper. More thrust required. So the question is: more kwh required?